# Installing jdk7 on Debian server via SSH

Tags: debian, software-installation, java

Currently, I'm trying to launch a java program on a server. The server is launched on my virtual machine (VirtualBox) and controlled over SSH. Its OS is Debian. So, in order to launch my program I need jdk7. I've downloaded its tar.gz archive to the server and extracted it to `/usr/jav`a. But the system can't see the new jdk. When I type "java -version" in my terminal it writes 1.6 instead of desired 1.7. So, a trivial question: how can I install jdk7 on Debian? (No GUI is available).

Comment: `/usr/java/` wont be in your path (or indeed `/usr/` if you put the java executable directly in there).  You already have some varient of java installed which is giving you the 1.6 - probably from a package.  Type `dpkg -S \`which java\``, what comes up?

Comment: Here's an output of that command:

dpkg: /usr/bin/java not found.

and how can I add a folder to the path?

Comment: OK so you have a `/usr/bin/java` that has got there from some other way - probably a manual install.  Do `ls -laF /usr/bin/java` and see what that gives you - does it point to `/etc/alternatives/java`?  If so, please then run `update-alternatives --list java` and post the results.  There are many different ways of getting Java on Debian.  Also post the list of directories under `/usr/java/`

Answer (score 1):

Simply extracting the archive's contents will not install your software. Check the folder where you extracted the files, there will be installation instructions there.

You can also try following [this guide](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/debianjava.htm) to create a debian package from the tar.gz archive.

Finally, jdk1.7 is in Debian's "experimental" repository. You can edit `/etc/apt/sources.lst` to include this line:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian experimental main
```

Then run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

**WARNING**: Depending on how up to date your system is, many packages might need to be updated which could result in an unstable system. Make sure you change your `/etc/apt/sources.lst` back to how it was before if you chose this method.

Comment: See also `apt` pinning possibilities at http://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences (or recompile from the experimental source package for your release = poor man's backport with `dpkg-buildpackage`); it's less dangerous!